# How can I pass URL parameters to a react application?

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a react app running on my development server at https://develop.dev/carslist fetching data from a REST API.

In this example a list of cars is rendered.

Mercedes Model 1
....
Audi Model 23

The REST API is able to handle parameters. What I would like to do now is to filter the manufacturer via url parameter.

Example:
https://develop.dev/carslist#manufacturer=mercedes

As far as I understood in react parameters should be passed with setState so that the application re-renders automatically.

But how can I do this? Or is it sufficent to parse window.location without setState when calling the API.

Comment: you can simply pass params as /url/`${param1}`/`${param2}` and so on

Comment: are u using reactrouter?

Comment: thank you. I am not sure if  I really need react router when I just want to read url parameter and pass them to the REST call.
I also need a key-value pair (manufacturer=mercedes) so I am not sure if I can handle key-value with /url/${param1}/${param2}

Comment: Until now I do not use react router.